# Modifying and RETURNING data in the same postgres command

Tags: update, postgresql-13

I have a simple bit of SQL to reset some values in a table

```
UPDATE tableA SET field1 = 0
WHERE field2 IN (SELECT .......)
```

This works fine, but I'd like to modify it to return the value of all `field1` values *before* they were reset to zero. This is what I've tried....

```
UPDATE tableA SET field1 = 0
WHERE field2 IN (SELECT .......)
RETURNING field1
```

The catch is that this only returns the values of field1 *after* being modified. Is it possible to get the value *beforehand*? without running a separate query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only option is to select the old values first, then return those:

Assuming there is a primary key column named `pk` you could do something like this:

```
with old_values as (
  select pk, column1 as old_column1_value
  from t1
  where column2 in (10,20)
), change as (
  update t1
    set column1 = 0 
  where pk in (select pk from old_values)
)
select *
from old_values
```

Passing the PK values from the first CTE ("old_values") to the CTE that updates the rows, avoids repeating the condition on column2 in the UPDATE statement.

**Edit:**

It occurred to me that this can be simplified due to the fact that the CTE does not see changes to the underlying tables.

```
with change as (
  update t1
    set column1 = 0 
  where column2 in (10,20)
  returning pk
)
select pk, column1 as old_value
from  t1
where pk in (select pk from change);
```